# How to get birthdate, location, etc from facebook api v2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get birthdate, location, etc from facebook api v2.4? 
Why Graph API returns to me only two fields(name and id)? Where other fields?

Comment: You should always post your code with what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thoughts would be to ensure that you have the correct permissions on your app to collect birthdays.

My second thought would be to try something like this:

```
$friends_birthday = $facebook->api("/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday");
```

But without knowing what you have tried (or even what language you are trying to do this in), trouble shooting is tough.

Comment: Thank you very much, I myself understand the problem, I just have no access rights to all personal user info.